# putting data from editText into a table

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android, I make tables in eclipse, and I want to retrieve the information entered by the user to put it in a table named user when pressing on the button REGISTER

What code should I wrote to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", number));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pwd));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hint", h));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_id", id));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) 
         {
          flag=0;   
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
          i.putExtra("mobile_number",number);
          i.putExtra("password",pwd);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
         }
         else
         {
            // failed to Sign in
            flag=1;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: As I know I should use OnClickListener to the button register, this method is complicated for me